# My Print Preview changes on different resolutions

Tags: printing, screen-resolution

in this link :

http://visamastercard.ir/uploads/VisaMaster/print.php?id=162

i want to print a visa request form in A4 size, when i want to print it via different resolutions it will corrupted! i want the Terms and Conditions section and sections before it in this print to be on page 1 and 3 next sections on page 2.not anymore pages! but it will corrupted on different screen resolutions.

for example : 
in 1280*1024 it will be printed in the right adjestment,but in 1600*900 it corrupted!

what is the difference?! isn't there a constant width and height for A4 size for printing????!!!! or this is relevant to screen resolution?!

Comment: is there anyone to help me????????!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Off course A4 size has fixed width and height.

You can check the custom size page for your requirement.

Comment: what do you mean?can you explain it to me?